# Magento 2: How to fix error `[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` when run setup:upgrade?

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade

I install lampp on lixnux. Then install Magento 2. However, i get some errors when run `setup:upgrade` and `setup:static-content:deploy`. Please see image:
[image]

Comment: I think you should set permissions 770/777 for  `pub` and `var` folder

Comment: The issue has yet to resolve. I think that is PDO MySQL error. Howerver, i can't find out how to fix it.

Comment: @MinhTamPham  can you  restart mysql then test it.

Comment: @Rajkumar.E I have tried many times. It can't be fixed.

Comment: follow this link http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_phpini.html

Comment: i think you need  Open up your php.ini file,   and change pdo_mysql.default_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock  reference http://prattski.com/2010/08/05/magento-install-mysql-error-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory/

Comment: @Rajkumar.E Thank you! I am a new user Ubuntu. I have read that document and perform some like that but i can't resolve the issue. Could you show how to fix? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 13):

This will happen in normal cases.

Go to,

**app/etc/env.php**

Change

```
'host' => 'localhost',
```

Into

```
'host' => '127.0.0.1'
```

Run the upgrade now.

Good Luck!

Comment: i do this but error still here:Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Comment: I see this fix everywhere, but I don’t understand how it works. Why would `localhost` not work?

Answer (score 7):

This can happen if you have multiple versions of PHP on your system.  For example, I had `/usr/bin/php` as well as the PHP from MAMP on my Mac, so running /usr/bin/php in the (cron job for indexing)

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#config-cli-cron-bkg
would give the error shown in the question.

To resolve, I called MAMP's version of PHP in the cron commands, e.g.:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.30/bin/php /Users/scott/Sites/mage_217/bin/magento cron:run
```

Comment: perfect answer!!! =1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @scott response or you can simply override the php.ini location and replace it with the one you have.

Here are the instruction for how to do that on Mac.

https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693

Answer (score 0):

first of all check your apache2 service

`service apache2 status` green mean its running.

Otherwise run `sudo systemctl start apache2` command to run the apache2 service,

and then check your mysql service is running or not.

run `service mysql status` green mean running.

otherwise run `sudo systemctl start mysql` to run the mysql service
then you are good to go.

refresh the page the error will be gone.

**Tip:** `service --status-all` will show all the running(`+`) and stop(`-`) services

Answer (score -1):

Simply replace the magento file in bin directory with the new one and run the following command on magento file if your host is linux:

[image]
**sudo chmod u+x bin/magento**

Note: Before running bash command make sure your current working directory must be Magento 2.x root.