# In Setup upgrade and cache clear i get an error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: magento2

I got some errors in my system (ubuntu 18.6) when I clean my cache and setup upgrade. and I am not localhost in URL I am using IP address.

[image: agen]

In Cache clean

[image]

Comment: Your php version??

Comment: PHP 7.2.24 version

Comment: Php72 bin/magento c:f try this

Comment: again get same error after cache flush.

Comment: Okay, you change the app/etc/env.php file

Comment: not working @mohit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105410/discussion-between-karuna-khatri-and-mohit-patel).

Comment: You check this linkhttps://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137909/magento-2-how-to-fix-error-zend-db-adapter-exception-sqlstatehy000-2002

Comment: can you explain to me when it has come? like have you added any extension or change something.

Comment: yeah i have add my custom module.

Comment: @KarunaKhatri ok so can you share me there sql upgrade file

Comment: Thank You @MohitPatel for helping yeah I change in my env.php file localhost to "127.0.0.1".

Comment: Your solution done???

Comment: yeah, it's done.

Comment: my answer helped you so i have create the full answer and you accept the answer ??? so useful to the another community ..

Comment: yeah sure @mohit Patel

Comment: Hello @KarunaKhatri any query another question this is my skype id let me know skype https://join.skype.com/invite/a8vGneX5XdBh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to,

And open the **app/etc/env.php**

Change

```
'host' => 'localhost',
```

Into

```
'host' => '127.0.0.1'
```

And the `php bin/magento s:up` now

Solve the issue..

Answer (score 0):

It's seem to be folder permission issue Try This Command in your root directory

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2
```

Comment: it's resolved. localhost problem.